# Non monotonic x range in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I would like to display a graph as a function of fractional hours, where the x axis jumps from 24 to 0 hours. However the plotted quantity should be joined smoothly accross date boundaries. I could use different time units in the x axis that increase monotonically, but I would like to display the hours at integer tick locations in the x axis, how could I do that?

```
hours = [19,20.5,21.5,22.5,23.5,0.5,1.5,2.5,3,4]
list1 = [random.randint(1,10) for x in range(10)]
plt.plot(hours, list1)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume the `hours` list is the result of stripping the time out of a more complete date structure?

If you convert the dates `datetime` objects (including the day information so they really are montonic), you can then directly plot `list1` against the dates.  You can then

```
import datetime

d = datetime.datetime.now()
delta = datetime.timedelta(hours=1)
dates = [d]
for j in range(20):
    dates.append(dates[-1] + delta)

date_list = dates
list1 = rand(len(dates))
figure()
ax = gca()
ax.plot(date_list,list1)
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(
    matplotlib.dates.HourLocator()
)
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(
    matplotlib.dates.DateFormatter('%H')
)
```

adapted from [here](http://stefaanlippens.net/pylab_date_tick_control)

[image: result of code]

Comment: Apparently this does not work, it sets the xlim to the minimum and maximum in the list of hours and assumes that they increase monotonically.

Comment: you have to include the date as well so that they really are monotonic.

Comment: The datetime objects included the date as well.

Comment: Great, thank you very much! I am using pyephem.Date types which I can then convert to datetime objects to use this method. I thought that was what I was doing previously but I made a mistake, sorry about that.

Answer (score 2):

Well, this is very dirty, and I'd try going with the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13712269/1258041) now that it's posted, but (in `ipython --pylab`):

```
In [1]: def monotonic_hours(h):
    hours = h[:]
    for i, _ in enumerate(h[1:], 1):
        while hours[i-1] > hours[i]:
            hours[i] += 24
    return hours
   ...: 

In [2]: %paste
hours = [19,20.5,21.5,22.5,23.5,0.5,1.5,2.5,3,4]
list1 = [random.randint(1,10) for x in range(10)]

## -- End pasted text --

In [3]: plot(monotonic_hours(hours), list1)
Out[3]: [<matplotlib.lines.Line2D at 0x3271810>]

In [4]: xticks(xticks()[0], [int(h%24) for h in xticks()[0]])
```

[image]

Note: this is accurate if the default `xticks` are at integer positions, otherwise you can do something like

```
ticks = sorted(set(int(round(t)) for t in xticks()[0]))
xticks(ticks, [h%24 for h in ticks])
```

Note 2: without `ipython` you can call everything on `plt`.